# How can I find the non-matching value between two items in an array in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have one Message.

Each Message has two User_Message objects

User_Message.user_id for one is the same as current_user.id.  the other is different.

How do I find the "other" value and output it?

My controller has @messages which is all the messages.

I am displaying each message in the view, use @message.do loop.

But I haven't come up with good logic, I tried the following:

```
1   def other_party(current_user)
 12     um = self.user_messages
 13     um.each do |user_message|
 14       debugger
 15       other_user = User.find(user_message.user_id) unless user_message.user_id == current_us    er.id
 16     end
 17 
 18     other_user 
 19   end
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def other_party(current_user)
   um = self.user_messages.find(:first,:conditions => ["user_id != ?",current_user.id])
   other_user = User.find(um.user_id)
end
```